# Cahill, Physical Mathematics, Exercise 7.14

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem: Integrate the ODE $(xy+1)dx+2x^{2}(2xy-1)dy=0$.

Hint given in the book (Kevin Cahill, Physical Mathematics Exercise 7.14, page 332, Second edition): Use the variable $v(x)=xy(x)$ instead of $y(x)$.

Now I tried solving this equation using the hint and separating the variables since:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dv}{dx}=f(x)g(v)
\end{equation}

where $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $g(v)=\frac{-(v+1)+2v(2v-1)}{2(2v-1)}$.

Separating and integrating gives me: $x=(v-1)^{2/5}+(4v+1)^{6}+c$.

But this is not helpful since I need to find $v=v(x)$ and from that $y=y(x)$ and inverting the above relation seems difficult. Have I done anything wrong here? Is there any other method to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have made a slip with integration and simplification.

Starting from here:
$$x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{1+3v-4v^2}{2(1-2v)},$$
you separate the variables and use partial fractions:
$$\int\frac1x dx=\int\frac{2(1-2v)}{(1+4v)(1-v)}dv=\int\frac{\frac{12}{5}}{1+4v}-\frac{\frac25}{1-v}dv$$
$$\implies\ln|x|=\frac35\ln|1+4v|+\frac25\ln|1-v|+c$$
And since $v=xy$,
$$\implies|x|^5=A|1+4xy|^3|1-xy|^2$$

But you won't be able to obtain $y=f(x)$ from this.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I wonder if it can be solved without using the hint. Also, I checked, this problem has survived two editions and I checked the errata too, which means there is a solution using the hint.

Comment: are you asking if there is a way of solving it *without* using the substitution $v=xy$?